# Azure Durable Function Python error in local test: HistoryEvent.__init__() missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: python, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to start the first Azure durable function following this demo document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=windows%2Cazure-cli-set-indexing-flag&pivots=python-mode-decorators

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
from src.main import engine_main
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

myApp = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@myApp.route(route="orchestrators/{functionName}")
@myApp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def http_start(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    function_name = req.route_params.get("functionName")
    instance_id = await client.start_new(function_name)
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
return response

@myApp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def hello_orchestrator(context):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "Seattle") 
    result2 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "Tokyo")
    result3 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "London")
    return [result1, result2, result]

@myApp.activity_trigger(input_name="city")
def hello(city: str):
    return city
```

I can see the function started. but when I send a request from my browser I get an error code in VS debug window:

> 'hello_orchestrator (Orchestrator)' failed with an error. Reason: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Result: Failure
> Exception: TypeError: HistoryEvent.**init**() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'EventType', 'EventId', 'IsPlayed', and 'Timestamp'

the stack of the error showed it was in

> .venv\lib\site-packages\azure\durable_functions\models\DurableOrchestrationContext.py", line 50, in <listcomp>
> self._histories: List[HistoryEvent] = [HistoryEvent(**he) for he in history]
> )

The error is eventually found in `.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\durable_functions\models\History\HistoryEvent.py` from the durable function library:

```
  def __init__(self, EventType: HistoryEventType, EventId: int, IsPlayed: bool, Timestamp: str,
             **kwargs):
    self._event_type: HistoryEventType = EventType
    self._event_id: int = EventId
    self._is_played: bool = IsPlayed
    self._timestamp: datetime.datetime = dt_parse(Timestamp)
    self._is_processed: bool = False
```

It is expecting four Pascal case parameters (`EventType`, `EventId`,`IsPlayed`and `TimeStamp`) as inputs but instead got four camel case parameters (`eventType`, `eventId`,`isPlayed`and `timeStamp`) which is taken from a json string taken from a queue and I cannot figure out further.

I have tried to deploy the code to Azure and the code actually worked. Is it because I am using Windows?

Thanks for the helps!

==========================
my software versions:

windows 11

VS code 1.77.2

Azure function runtime: Function Runtime Version: 4.14.0.19631

Python: 3.10.11 (and 3.9.13)

azure-functions==1.13.3 (version undefined in requirements.txt)

azure-functions-durable==1.2.2 (version undefined in requirements.txt)

==========================
My progress so far:

1. Deploy the code to Azure and it works! Checked the Azure setting, and it is using Python 3.10.4, Debian Linux, and the packages are the same
2. Switch to durable function python V1 and got the same error
3. Reinstall the packages and it does not work either
4. I found test code in `.venv\lib\site-packages\tests\models\test_DurableOrchestrationContext.py` so indeed they are expecting Pascal case inputs.

   ```
   @pytest.fixture
   def starting_context():
   context = DurableOrchestrationContext.from_json(
       '{"history":[{"EventType":12,"EventId":-1,"IsPlayed":false,'
       '"Timestamp":"2019-12-08T23:18:41.3240927Z"}, '
   ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code has been attached. Also updated my debug progress.

Comment: "It is expecting four Pascal case parameters (EventType, EventId,IsPlayedand TimeStamp) as inputs but instead got four camel case parameters (eventType, eventId,isPlayedand timeStamp) which is taken from a json string taken from a queue and I cannot figure out further." - no, the error message clearly says that it did not get anything passed at all. What part of the code do you think is supposed to case the values to be taken from a json string from a queue? (what string? what queue?)

Comment: Anyway, arguments to a function are *values, not variables*; it does not matter how they are calculated (whether it's just a variable name, or a literal value, or a more complicated expression) and it certainly does not matter what the case of a variable name is.

Comment: "I found test code in .venv\lib\site-packages\tests\models\test_DurableOrchestrationContext.py so indeed they are expecting Pascal case inputs." No, this is different. It is calling a method named `from_json`, which (we can assume) will read the json and create the values to pass to the `__init__`. However, the error message tells us that *this did not get used*. In the code that was actually called, it used `[HistoryEvent(**he) for he in history]`, which tries to provide the parameters from dictionary instead. But the dictionary is empty.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In VS code, I put a breakpoint in the `DurableOrchestrationContext.py` and checked the `history` variable, there are 2 dicts with keys like `eventType` but no keys like `EventType`.

Comment: When I manually change the code in `HistoryEvent.py` to `def __init__(self, eventType: HistoryEventType, eventId: int, isPlayed: bool, timestamp: str,**kwargs):  ` the code may continue but still get an error later. Besides, it works when I deploy the code to Azure. which indicates the code is correct, just my setting or environment